# Xquery: Get Previous week days

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, xpath-2.0

Is it possible to get the days(mon-sun) of the previous week in xquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [FunctX XQuery Library](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/c0002.html), they offer a great overview on and also some additional date functions.

Use this pattern to eg. calculate the date 7 days before:

```
fn:current-date() - xs:dayTimeDuration('P7D')
```

[FunctX' `day-of-week()`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_day-of-week.html) will help you in calculating the day of week for a date.

As parsing the whole FunctX library can make your queries really slow (depending on your XQuery engine), maybe only copy the code you need.

This code will return the week days of the last 7 days (last week seen as a period). The code includes Gunther's fix to `functx:day-of-week` which he described in the comments:

```
declare namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com"; 
declare function functx:day-of-week 
  ( $date as xs:anyAtomicType? )  as xs:integer? {

  if (empty($date))
  then ()
  else xs:integer((xs:date($date) - adjust-date-to-timezone(xs:date('1901-01-06'), timezone-from-date(xs:date($date)))
          div xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')) mod 7
 } ;

for $day in 1 to 7
let $date := fn:current-date() - xs:dayTimeDuration(concat('P', 8-$day, 'D'))
return <day date="{ $date }">{ functx:day-of-week($date) }</day>
```

If this is not exactly you're looking for (please always include some code you thought about, the input and expected output in your questions), I'm sure you will be able to change it to fit your needs.

Comment: Be warned, though, that functx:day-of-week has a small problem, because it does not handle timezones correctly, and this could possibly affect the solution. It can be fixed by replacing `xs:date('1901-01-06')` in its implementation by `adjust-date-to-timezone(xs:date('1901-01-06'), timezone-from-date(xs:date($date)))`. I had reported that to Priscilla about a year ago, but apparently the site hasn't been updated since.

Comment: I added your fix to the answer above.

Comment: After writing my previous comment, I realized that the problem would not affect the very solution, because `xs:date('1901-01-06')`, before being subtracted, should be mapped to the implicit timezone - the same that `current-date()` is equipped with. However as it turns out, BaseX appears to be incorrectly using timezone Z in that case. I have put a note on their mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

**Another solution, which happens to be a pure XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
for $vSunday in xs:date('2012-07-08'),
    $thisWeekDay in
       abs((current-date() - $vSunday) div xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D'))
      mod 7 +1,
    $lastWeekSunday in
       current-date() - xs:dayTimeDuration(concat('P',$thisWeekDay+7,'D')),
    $i in 1 to 7,
    $d in $lastWeekSunday + xs:dayTimeDuration(concat('P', $i, 'D'))
  return
    (concat(year-from-date($d),
            '-', month-from-date($d),
            '-', day-from-date($d)),
     ('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday')
                                                                        [$i],
     '&#xA;')
```

**When run today (2012-07-08) the result is**:

```
 2012-7-1 Sunday 
 2012-7-2 Monday 
 2012-7-3 Tuesday 
 2012-7-4 Wednesday 
 2012-7-5 Thursday 
 2012-7-6 Friday 
 2012-7-7 Saturday
```